# Application.ThreadException fires before try... catch block

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have being searching an answer to understand try... catch behavior when I use it in an application which has an Application.ThreadException handler attached.

So, the context is:

in main() I have:

```
Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
```

Later, in some form button click event I have the following code, to start another form with showdialog():

```
try
{
    var secondForm = new(secondForm);
    secondForm.ShowDialog(this);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ///do something
}
```

The problem is: if I attach an Application.ThreadException event handler on main(), the try... catch block in the code above catches nothing, and Application.ThreadException event handler is executed.
If I remove the Application.ThreadException event handler, try... catch block works as expected.

Why? Any workaround?

**Note:** here you have almost the same question, 4 years ago, but not answered:
[try catch not working properly in WinForms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654058/try-catch-not-working-properly-in-winforms-application)

Comment: You can use try catch or the ThreadException event **on the UI thread** but not both at the same time.

Comment: Hi Sir Rufo, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure to understand it. If i generate an exception directly on try {...} body, is catched corerctly.  Does not matter if i had setup an Application.ThreadException event handler or not.

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - so we can drag/drop the code and compile it